# WooCommerce product categories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I hope you're all having a great day. I have a question regarding WooCommerce product categories. Specifically, I'm interested in knowing if there is a way to add heading structure to the product category pages.
Is there anyone who has experience or knowledge about this? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You'd probably have to edit the templates for those in your theme.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.